# drawing from a byte array in java LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d, raycasting

I am creating a raycaster using java, LWJGL and Slick2D.
The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to draw from this byte array correctly.

This is how I put my texture into the colorbuffer. This works. All the RGB values are the same as the ones in the texture.

```
    public java.awt.Color[] colorBuffer;
for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            c = new java.awt.Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
            colorBuffer[y * Width + x] = c;}}
```

now here is how I create my screenbuffer and assign pixels to it:

```
static byte[] buffer;
static int screenTexture;

public static void main() {
        buffer = new byte[Display.Height * Display.Width];
        screenTexture = GL11.glGenTextures();
        texture = new Sprite(new Vector2f(0, 0), "src/Content/Textures/tex1.bmp");
}

// in the raycasting algorithm:
buffer[y * Display.Width + x] = (byte) texture.colorBuffer[texY * texture.Width + texX].getRed();
                buffer[y * Display.Width + x + 1] = (byte) texture.colorBuffer[texY * texture.Width + texX].getGreen();
                buffer[y * Display.Width + x + 2] = (byte) texture.colorBuffer[texY * texture.Width + texX].getBlue();
                buffer[y * Display.Width + x + 3] = (byte) texture.colorBuffer[texY * texture.Width + texX].getAlpha();
```

and here is how I draw the buffer:

```
org.newdawn.slick.Color.white.bind();
        ByteBuffer b = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(buffer.length * 4); // times four due to every pixel having RGBA.
        for (int a = 0; a < buffer.length; a++) {
            b.put(a, buffer[a]);
        }
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, Display.Width / 4, Display.Height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, b);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        {
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(Display.Width, 0);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(Display.Width, Display.Height);

            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(0, Display.Height);
        }
        GL11.glEnd();
```

Now, say if I create a texture which are 3 vertical lines: red, green and blue. It will make the red one white and the others pitchblack, as well as adding a few colors to the texture the further it is in the distance.

Here is an image of what it looks like. The paint file is the original texture, and the right window is the raycaster.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LWeU.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Completely unrelated, what is that view in your lower-left corner that  lets you navigate classmembers?

Answer (score 1):

You souldn't use an array of awt.Color objects. Use a ByteArray instead, which represent RGB(A) values on 32 bits.

Here is my implementation :

```
 /**
 * conversion des Images java en buffer
 * 
 * @param source image java
 * @param x0 gauche
 * @param x1 droite
 * @param y0 haut
 * @param y1 bas
 * @param colormode nombre de canaux à lire dans l'image
 * @return buffer
 */
public static ByteBuffer byteBufferFromImageBuffer(BufferedImage source, int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1, int colormode) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer((x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0)
            * colormode);
    switch (colormode) {
    case 1:
        for (int y = y0; y < y1; y++) {
            for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++) {
                int pixel = source.getRGB(x, y);
                buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF)); // Blue component
            }
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        for (int y = y0; y < y1; y++) {
            for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++) {
                int pixel = source.getRGB(x, y);
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF)); // Red component
                buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF)); // Green component
                buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF)); // Blue component
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        for (int y = y0; y < y1; y++)
            for (int x = x0; x < x1; x++)
                buffer.putInt(source.getRGB(x, y));
        break;
    default:
        warn("bad colormode");
        break;
    }

    buffer.flip(); 
    // reste a effectuer les oppérations OGL depuis le thread principal
    return buffer;
            // now you can call buffer2GLTex() from rendering thread.
}

     /**
 * pour LWJGL convertit une bitmap bufferisée en texture. Après cette étape,
 * le buffer peut-être détruit
 * 
 * @param openGL tex id
 * @param w largeur en pixel du buffer
 * @param h hauteur en pixel du buffer
 * @param buffer data
 * @param colormode la texture sera noir et blanc (1), rgb (3) ou rgba(4)
 */
public static void buffer2GLTex(int tex, int w, int h, ByteBuffer buffer, int colormode) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);


    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    int texFiltering = TexLinFilter ? GL_LINEAR : GL_NEAREST;

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, texFiltering);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, texFiltering);

    // Generate The Texture
    int format = 0;
    switch (colormode) {
    case 1:
        format = GL_LUMINANCE;
        break;
    case 3:
        format = GL_RGB;
        break;
    case 4:
                    // format = GL_RGBA;
        format = GL_BGRA;
        break;

    default:
        err("bad colormode");
        break;
    }
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ColorMode, w, h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    glErr(glGetError());
}
```

This is far from perfect, but it's what I use, it works fine for me !

Hope it helps